# Simple android studio app is crashing when i run it. it have no errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, crash

i made a simple betting app for me and my friend.
I press one button from the bottom  to set the value of the bid. and after that if i win i press i win and otherwise i press i lost. when i press i lost or i win the text view get the value of the bet. I dont have any errors , i dont know why is it crashing when i open the app.
[image]
here is the code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int totalMoney= 0;
int betValue = 0;
String savedMoney;

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    public void clickP(View view){

        totalMoney= totalMoney - betValue;
    }
    public void clickC(View view){

        totalMoney= totalMoney + betValue;
    }
    public void click1(View view){

       betValue = 1;
    }
    public void click2(View view){

       betValue = 2;
    }
    public void click3(View view){

         betValue = 3;
    }
    public void click4(View view){

         betValue = 4;
    }
    public void click5(View view){

         betValue = 5;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            savedMoney = textView.getText().toString();

            totalMoney = Integer.parseInt(savedbani);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.markusappcompany.baniipemasa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            sharedPreferences.edit().putInt("Money", totalMoney).apply();

            sharedPreferences.getInt("Money", totalMoney);

            textView.setText(totalMoney);


    }
}
```

This is what i get in Logcat:

```
05-22 19:54:52.918 20536-20536/com.markusappcompany.baniipemasa E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.markusappcompany.baniipemasa, PID: 20536
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.markusappcompany.baniipemasa/com.markusappcompany.baniipemasa.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:338)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5494)
                                                                                      at com.markusappcompany.baniipemasa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.markusappcompany.baniipemasa.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="117dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        android:text="I LOST"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="117dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        android:text="I WIN"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="1 EUR"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
        android:text="2 EUR"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
        android:text="3 EUR"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
        android:text="4 LEI"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="148dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:text="5 LEI"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="163dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="221dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="190dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="Total money:"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't post stacktrace and codes as images post them as plain text

Comment: post your error as a code

Comment: i`ve posted an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you remove all click methods your activity should look like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int totalMoney= 0;
int betValue = 0;
String savedMoney;
TextView textView 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Button yourButton = findViewById(R.layout.yourButtonId)
        Button yourButton2 = findViewById(R.layout.yourButtonId2)
        // for all Buttons

}}
```

You also must give the button an id in the activity_main file. After that you have to implement an onClickListener for all thes buttons like this:

```
yourButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
// the same for every Button
```

then you add this line:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

at the end the listener:

```
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.yourButtonID:
                     // when button with this ID is clicked do your stuff here 
                case R.id.otherButtonID:
                     // when button with this ID is clicked do your stuff here 

}
```

}

Here the explanation first you find the buttons and the textView after that you set an onclicklistener so when you click one button the button call the method onClick. The switch statment is called an finds out which button is called.

Comment: i am getting this error now: setOnClickListener
(android.view.View.OnClickListener)
in View cannot be applied
to
 (com.markusappcompany.baniipemasa.MainActivity) . i get it at : button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this); etc . "this" is underscored

Comment: Just paste the onClick method UNDER the onCreate method and could you post your xml code

Comment: now the app is opening but no buttons are not working

Comment: also the public in public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the Buttons and textViews in the onCreate method. 
Also try to handle the Buttons with OnClickListener like this:

```
Button yourButtton = findViewById(R.id.yourButttonID);
yourButtton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And this for all Buttons.
then:

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.yourButtonID:
            // when button with this ID is clicked 
        case R.id.otherButtonID:
            // when button with this ID is clicked 

    }
}
```

Comment: And write the onCreate method at to top directly after the class just for simpler overview

Comment: Hello sir, unfortunately I am a beginner and I do not understand the code written by you, I do not know how to model it to match my code. I have errors

Comment: I posted a new answer

Answer (score 0):

Place your Textview's findTextViewById inside OnCreateView.